# GitHub not showing GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have a feeling this was addressed before but did not find a clear answer so far. I have this YAML file stored in `.github/workflows/`.

It's supposed to run a Python script and then output/modify an XML file. I don't see the action in GitHub Actions though. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my workflow:

```yaml
name: Update RSS feed

on:
  schedule:
    # Set the cron schedule to your desired interval (e.g. every day at 12:00 UTC).
    - cron: '32 22 * * *'
    push:
      branches:
        - main
    workflow_dispatch:
      branches:
        - main

jobs:
  update-feed:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      # Give the default GITHUB_TOKEN write permission to commit and push the
      # added or changed files to the repository.
      contents: write
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your script can access it.
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Set up Python and install dependencies.
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.9.6' # Replace with your desired Python version.

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip3 install -r requirements.txt

      # Run the Python script to generate the RSS feed.
      - name: Generate RSS feed
        run: python3 feed-create.py

      # Commit the updated RSS feed to the GitHub Pages branch.
      - name: Commit changes
        uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
        with:
          commit_message: "Update filtered RSS feed"
          branch: ${{ github.ref }}
          commit_user_name: "GitHub Actions"
          commit_user_email: "actions@github.com"
          file_pattern: "filtered-rss-feed.xml"
          commit_options: "--no-verify --signoff"
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: when do you see that the action is not being executed? when you do a push to main branch? when you try to run it manually? are you sure that `workflow_dispatch` have an attribute `branches`? also it looks like it is not well indented

Comment: Multiple syntax errors in your workflow: `on` section is not properly aligned i.e. `push` and `workflow_dispatch` should be at `schedule` level. Use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to validate and fix your workflow. Also, [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatch) doesn't support `branches`. Fixing these should make your workflow valid and it should start appearing.

Comment: Thx to all of you. I did indeed need to fix some indentation and the cron run time. Because this is the first time I use GH workflows, I think I also did not put the yaml file in the right place....ooops! I didn't know also that GH has a workflow build tool in the Actions tab.

Answer (score 0):

The cron definition 32 32 * * * specifies that the job should be run at minute 32 and hour 32, every day of the month, week, and year. However, there are no minutes or hours that are 32, so this definition will never be triggered.

A valid definition given the comment you have would be:
`0 12 * * *`

Then you also have this indentation problem:

```
on:
  schedule:
    # Set the cron schedule to your desired interval (e.g. every day at 12:00 UTC).
    - cron: '0 12 * * *'
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches:
      - main
```

Comment: Thx Roberto. I changed my cron so that it actually runs at a time that exists!